# Columns Values are getting changed to date format in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is my DataFrame called as Data

```
Column A    Column B
1              A
2              B
3              C
```

I use Dictionery to map column A

```
Dict = {'1':'0', '2':'1-9','3':'10-29','4':'30-49','5':'50+'}

Data['Column A'] = Data['Column A'].astype(str).map(Dict )
```

This returns output as bellow

```
Column A    Column B
0             A
09-Jan        B
29-Oct        C
```

here it is changing '1-9' to '09-jan' & the same way '10-29' to '29-oct'
How ca i prevent it from changing the values.

Comment: I think it change only excel, data are correct.

Comment: @jezrael how to prevent it changing in excel

Comment: To check if your data is correct, in your code just print your dataframe. If its an excel problem, you can prevent to change numbers to dates following : https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8

Answer (score 1):

what you want to prevent in Column A I am getting the same values which you are expecting,

```
import datetime

Data=pd.DataFrame(data={'Column A':[1,2,3],'Column B':['A','B','C']})
Dict = {'1':'0', '2':'1-9','3':'10-29','4':'30-49','5':'50+'}

Data['Column A'] = Data['Column A'].astype(str).map(Dict )
```

**Output**

```
    Column A    Column B
0          0    A
1        1-9    B
2      10-29    C
```

Answer (score 1):

Confirm your data type:

```
type(Data['Column A'][0])
```